# Django REST framework makes huge queries when rendering browsable HTML

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

When rendering a model `Model1` that has a `models.ManyToManyField` field to another model `Model2` that has ~50K entries in the DB, the default browsable HTML rendering takes about **3s** to answer, while JSON rendering takes around **30ms**.

Turning on the Django Debug Toolbar, shows that the following SQL request :

```
SELECT `app_model2`.`id`, `app_model2`.`field1` ... FROM `app_model2`;
```

takes almost **2s** by itself.

That query is triggered when rendering the line 14 of https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/522d45354633f080288f82ebe1535ef4abbf0b6e/rest_framework/templates/rest_framework/horizontal/select_multiple.html#L14

Is there a way to prevent the rendering to do such expensive SQL request?
In our case, we don't expect something more than just the `id` from these `Model2` entries to be rendered.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using it in django-admin and you have a multiple choice field there. If that is the case you can use `raw_id_fields` to prevent fetching all options.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/

Comment: I don't use django-admin, only django-rest-framework.